# How to change opacity in javascript canvas

Tags: javascript, dom, canvas

```
function Paint(){
var Size = document.getElementById('Size').value;
var Opacity = document.getElementById('opa').value;
var color = document.getElementById('color').value;
canvas = document.getElementById('PaintArea');
if(canvas.getContext){
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(musX-10, musY-10, Size, 0, Math.PI*2); 
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}
}
```

As you can see i have the fillStyle by a user input in my HTML, but how do i get the opacity in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: [**Updated**]

```
ctx.globalAlpha = Opacity;
```

Or just set the value:

```
ctx.globalAlpha = 0.2;
```

Comment: Worked! I had to do "ctx.globalAlpha = Opacity"

Answer (score 0):

Please use fillstyle with color:

```
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)";
```

For Image please use:

```
context.globalAlpha = 0.5;
```

Here is the complete link:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_globalalpha.asp